# Specific duplicate selection in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates, multiple-conditions

I did take a look in and outside of SO and still don't know if this can be done.  I have a table that looks like this:

```
User ID | Role | First Name | Last Name | Email |<br>
0001    | K    | John       | Smith     | e@e.co|<br>
0002    | Q    | Jane       | Dickens   | q@q.co|<br>
0003    | K    | John       | Smith     | e@e.co|<br>
0004    | J    | Jack       | Paper     | j@j.co|<br>
```

As you can see, the table contains a duplicate due to a user entering their information two separate times.  I want to display the rows that

1. have the same first name

2. have the same last name

3. have the same email

4. do NOT have the same User ID

I can get the first three conditions to work with an inner join subquery, but I get 0 returned results when ever I try to to add in the fourth condition.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`User ID`) as IDs, Role, `First Name`, `Last Name`, Email
FROM users_table
GROUP BY Role,`First Name`,`Last Name`,Email
```

Will give a table like

```
IDs       | Role | First Name | Last Name | Email |
0001,0003 |   K  |    John    |   Smith   | e@e.co|
0002      |   Q  |    Jane    |  Dickens  | q@q.co|
0004      |   J  |    Jack    |   Paper   | j@j.co|
```

**The trick is to `GROUP BY` everything except `ID`.**

You could also do:

```
SELECT COUNT(`User ID`) as numIDs, GROUP_CONCAT(`User ID`) as IDs, 
       Role, `First Name`, `Last Name`, Email
FROM users_table
GROUP BY Role,`First Name`,`Last Name`,Email
HAVING numIDs > 1
```

to get

```
numIDs |IDs       | Role | First Name | Last Name | Email |
    2  |0001,0003 |   K  |    John    |   Smith   | e@e.co|
```

Anyhow, you get the point of how to vary it to your purposes.

Comment: This is most likely what I'm using, it's still not quite what I'm trying to get for results, but that group_concat pushed me along.  Super thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
select *
  from tb_users
 where (first_name, last_name, email) in
   (select first_name, last_name, email
      from tb_users
     group by first_name, last_name, email
    having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your table does not contain true duplicate rows (where the User ID also matches). I think it should be as simple as this to get the relevant rows back (with my adjusted column and table naming scheme):

```
SELECT ui.user_id, ui.role, ui.first_name, ui.last_name, ui.email
FROM user_info AS ui
  INNER JOIN user_info AS udi
    ON ui.first_name = udi.first_name
      AND ui.last_name = udi.last_name
      AND ui.email = udi.email
      AND ui.user_id != udi.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use count(*) and group by clause.

Like this
SELECT count(*) as `count` FROM table group by concat(firstname,'\n',last_name) having `count`=1;

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to delete duplicate rows. Only take count by group by and delete duplicate rows.

```
select * from tb_users
     group by first_name, last_name, email
    having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to download extensions; go left bottom corner, click settings, click Keyboard Shortcuts, and search "duplication". You should see as in the below image and assign the key combination you want. I choose shift+D because I don't want to lose the current behavior of ctrl+D it is also very beneficial.

[image: Duplicate selection]